# Extracting a dataframe with unique elements from a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Hi I got a list like that

```
$`2`
  chr.pos  nt.pos CNV GRP
      1  783605   1   2
      1  888149   1   2
      1  991311   1   2
      1 1089305   1   2
      1 1177669   1   2

$`4`
 chr.pos  nt.pos CNV GRP
      2 1670488   1   4
      2 1758800   1   4

$`6`
 chr.pos  nt.pos CNV GRP
      2 1902924   1   6
      2 1978088   1   6
```

and I want to extract for each element,  the unique chromosome, the CNV and the group and the highest and lowest nt.pos, so the output would be, I prefer a data frame

```
chr.pos  Start     End       GRP
 1         783605    1177669   2
 2         1670488   175880    4
 2         1902924   1978088   6
```

I tried with this

```
results<-lapply(mylist, function(x){

return(as.data.frame(unique(x$chr.pos),range(x$nt.pos)[1],range(x$nt.pos)  [2],unique(x$GRP)))

}
)
```

But of course, what I got is a list.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick: (Assuming `dat` is your list of data frames.)

```
structure(
    as.data.frame(cbind(do.call(rbind,
                                lapply(dat,
                                       function(x) c(x[["chr.pos"]][1], 
                                                     range(x[["nt.pos"]])))),
                        as.numeric(names(dat)))),
    .Names = c("chr.pos", "Start", "End", "GRP"))

#   chr.pos   Start     End GRP
# 2       1  783605 1177669   2
# 4       2 1670488 1758800   4
# 6       2 1902924 1978088   6
```

Comment: Check out `setNames()`: `setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(dat, function(x) c(x[["chr.pos"]][1], range(x[["nt.pos"]]), x[["GRP"]][1])))), c("chr.pos", "Start", "End", "GRP"))` -- this also gets rid of the extra `cbind`.

Comment: +1 Good point @mrdwab I wasn't aware of the `setNames` function. This is much more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your list is named "dat", as below:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "chr.pos  nt.pos CNV GRP
1  783605   1   2
1  888149   1   2
1  991311   1   2
1 1089305   1   2
1 1177669   1   2
2 1670488   1   4
2 1758800   1   4
2 1902924   1   6
2 1978088   1   6")
dat <- split(dat, dat$GRP)
```

First, a question: do you really need it as a `list`, or can it just be a long `data.frame`? If it has to remain a list, perhaps try the following:

1. sapply()

   ```
   data.frame(t(sapply(dat, function(x) 
     data.frame(chr.pos = unique(x["chr.pos"]), 
                Start = min(x["nt.pos"]), 
                End = max(x["nt.pos"]), 
                GRP = unique(x["GRP"])))))
   ```
2. lapply()

   ```
   do.call(rbind, lapply(dat, function(x) 
     data.frame(chr.pos = unique(x["chr.pos"]), 
                Start = min(x["nt.pos"]), 
                End = max(x["nt.pos"]), 
                GRP = unique(x["GRP"]))))
   ```

Both will result in:

```
#   chr.pos   Start     End GRP
# 2       1  783605 1177669   2
# 4       2 1670488 1758800   4
# 6       2 1902924 1978088   6
```

Second, if it can be a long `data.frame`, then explore `data.table()`:

```
library(data.table)
DaT <- data.table(do.call(rbind, dat), key = "GRP")
DaT[, list(chr.pos = unique(chr.pos),
           Start = min(nt.pos),
           End = max(nt.pos)), by = key(DaT)]
#    GRP chr.pos   Start     End
# 1:   2       1  783605 1177669
# 2:   4       2 1670488 1758800
# 3:   6       2 1902924 1978088
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sven,

I did it in a similar way using this

```
N <- length(results)  #
DF <- data.frame(chr=rep(NA, N), Start=rep(NA, N), End=rep(NA,N), Group=rep(NA,N), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(results)){

  DF[i, ] <- c(unique(results[[i]]$chr.pos), range(results[[i]]$nt.pos)[1], range(results[[i]]$nt.pos)[2],unique(results[[i]]$GRP))

}
```

Comment: I would suggest exploring how the other solutions to this answer work before settling on this solution. `lapply` and `sapply` are both very useful functions to know if you are dealing with lists regularly.